# Match multiple exact routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am creating a function that checks if the current url matchs exactly the format I want.

I want to "check in bulk" if the current URL is part of an acceptable list of URLs.

I managed to do it with REGEX:

```
  const validateOpinionPath = (currentUrl: string): boolean => {

    const regexPatter = /opinion\/[0-9a-z-]*\/(large|medium|small)$/g
    const matchResult = currentUrl.match(regexPatter)
    return !!matchResult
  }
```

**HOWEVER** I would like to know how can I do the same by using `matchPath` (or any other function provided by `react-router-dom`).

**I tried** the following but it matches only the first URL:

```
  const validateOpinionPath = (currentUrl: string): boolean => {
    const match = matchPath(currentUrl, {
      path:
        '/option/:opinionId/large' ||
        '/option/:opinionId/medium' ||
        '/opinion/:opinionId/small',
      exact: true,
      strict: false
    })

    return !!match
  }
```

I want to match exactly these routes:

```
 '/option/:opinionId/large',
 '/option/:opinionId/medium',
 '/opinion/:opinionId/small'
```

`'/option/:opinionId/large/something'` should return `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason why multiple strings separated by `||` operator doesn't works is because second string will only be selected as the value of the `path` property if first string is a falsy value, for example an empty string.

Since, in your case, first string is not a falsy value, value of the `path` property is always the first string, i.e. `'/option/:opinionId/large'`.

#### Solution

You can pass an array of strings as a value of `path` property in options object passed to `matchPath()`. This way each path will be checked instead of just the first one.

```
const match = matchPath(currentUrl, {
  path: [
     '/option/:opinionId/large',
     '/option/:opinionId/medium',
     '/opinion/:opinionId/small'
  ],
  exact: true,
  strict: false
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work!

```
    const validateOpinionPath = (currentUrl: string): boolean => {
      const match = matchPath(currentUrl, {
        path: '/option/:opinionId/*'
        exact: true,
        strict: false
      })
      return !!match
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited my answer, I exactly need to match that URLs without additional `/something` at the end

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: Yes, I selected the one of @Yousaf

Answer (score 0):

React router dom uses [path-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp).

Your path can be:

```
/option/:optionId/(small|medium|large)
```